# Is there anyway to make hotlinking expire immediately for a website

Tags: php, hotlinking

I would like all links in the person's history to expire immediately so that when you click on them, it just takes you to the home page.

I would also like it to apply to the back buttons, so that when you click the back button it takes you back to the home page.

I know it's doable as glype, (a proxy script) does it. The problem is that it takes an hour for the links to expire, I would like it to happen immediately.

I do have an idea, but I feel as if there is an easier way to go about it than storing an id for every website that dynamically changes.

Thanks!

-Michael

Answer (score 0):

In the origin page where you make the link to your expiring page, you can make a "signed" URL which will include time stamp and user IP at the time you make the link. Once a user comes to your web page using the outdated signed URL or just un-signed URL, you will check current stamp and stamp for user link and just make re-direction.

We used similar approach in WMSAuth technology for [Windows Media](http://wmsauth.org/examples) and [for Wowza Media](http://blog.wmspanel.com/2012/05/protecting-wowza-from-re-publishing-re.html).